# Erro programação C, como fazer isso funcionar

Tags: c

```
#include <C:\Users\Rosangela\Desktop\exercicios\bibliotecaFuncao.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void paraBaixo(char *nome)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i>strlen(*nome);i++)
    {
        *nome[i] + 32;// o erro é aqui pois diz que não é possivel usar inteiros, mas como faria sem ser dessa forma?
    }
}

main()
{
    char nome[25];

    printf("Insira um nome: \n");
    gets(nome);

    paraBaixo(&nome);
    printf("Nomo com tudo em minusculo: %s",nome);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Voce esta percorrendo a string de forma errada.

Um `for` e executado enquanto a condicao logica dele, o segundo parametro, e verdadeiro:

```
for (inicializacao ; condicao; passo)
```

certo?

Agora pense: se o seu `i` comeca com `0`, ele nunca vai ser maior que o comprimento da sua string `nome`. Logo, voce precisa trocar para:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(nome); ++i)
```

2) Vetores em `C` (logo, strings, que sao vetores de caracteres tambem) ja sao ponteiros implicitamente. Logo, para usar a string nome na funcao `paraBaixo`, voce nao usa o `*`. Tambem, quando voce faz o `nome[i] + 32`, voce precisa guardar de volta no proprio `nome[i]`, ja que, caso contrario, o resultado e 'jogado fora':

```
void paraBaixo(char *nome)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(nome);i++)
    {
         nome[i] = nome[i] + 32;
    }
}
```

3) Agora, so mais questoes 'estilisticas':

- Declare a `main` como `int main()` e adicione um `return 0;` no final dela. E um bom habito em `C`;
- A funcao `gets` e deprecada e perigosa, tanto e que o meu compilador emite esse *warning* quando eu compilo seu programa: "warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used." E melhor voce trocar por um dos dois:

  scanf("%s", nome);

ou

```
fgets(nome, 25, stdin);
```

No fim, recomendo algo como:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void paraBaixo(char *nome)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(nome);i++)
    {
        nome[i] = nome[i] + 32;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char nome[25];

    printf("Insira um nome: \n");
    fgets(nome, 25, stdin);

    paraBaixo(nome);

    printf("Nomo com tudo em minusculo: %s\n",nome);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendi muito obrigado :D, só me resta uma duvida, por exemplo aqui no void paraBaixo(char *nome) se eu passar o argumento sendo uma string normal sem o '*(ponteiro)' ele funciona normal então qual é a necessidade de passar o argumento como ponteiro?

Comment: Muito bem explicado! Obs: A função `paraBaixo` está errada, pois para deixar um texto em minúsculo é preciso verificar antes se a letra era maiúscula. Ou seja `if(nome[i] <= 90) nome[i] = nome[i] + 32;` (90 = Z em decimal).

Comment: @user11504 `char *nome` e um vetor de caracteres. Se voce nao passar desse jeito a funcao vai achar que e um caracter so. @Peoplee como parece ser exercicio de curso introdutorio acho que nao e muito relevante validar os dados :P Ainda mais quando ela poderia usar a funcao pronta da ctype.h XD

Comment: eu estou passando sem o `char *nome` e está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Como assim sem o parametro? So `char nome`? Nao deveria compilar, ja que um `char` so nao e indexavel.

Comment: só `char nome` não, estou passando `char nome[25]`, é errado fazer desta forma? e outra pergunta eu não usei o fgets pois quando vou imprimir ele pega caracter aleatorio..., por isso usei o gets, o scanf da muito problema também tento evita-lo.

Comment: Ah, e equivalente. Sem problemas. O `fgets` e melhor pq voce passa o tamanho maximo da string, mas vai do seu gosto XD

Comment: Valeu mesmo cara obrigado, mas o problema do `fgets` é que ele pega caracter aleatorio quando vou imprimir, isso é ruim...